# how to get all line segments of a line intersecting a polygon in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, spatial-query

The intersection of one line and one (concave) polygon can result in several line segments.  When I use `SDO_LENGTH` on the result of `SDO_INTERSECTION`, it computes the length of the first segment only.  How to get the total length of all intersecting segments ?

```
select SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH(
    SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(polygon.Geometry, line.Geometry,0.01),
    0.01 )
from polygon, line 
<join, where>
```

[image]

Comment: Also, if I convert the line to a polygon using SDO_BUFFER, the SDO_INTERSECTION generates a Java error !